# Swift optional downcasting as Any

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, optional-variables

If we are trying access optional object property can we do like this -

```
var obj: Person

var str = obj.name? as Any
```

is this the right way to handle a `nil` case in swift3?

Comment: Form perspective of real life does a person ever have no name? Consider `name` to declare as non- optional. This makes the issue groundless.

Comment: I have just given the example here to clear my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to handle nil in swift:

**1. Use of if-let statement**

```
    var obj: Person
    if let name = obj.name {
        var str = name
    }
```

You can also check **type** of `obj.name` variable here as

```
    var obj: Person
    if let name = obj.name as? String {
        var str = name
    }
```

**2. Use of guard-let statement**

```
    var obj: Person
    guard let name = obj.name as? String else {
        return
    }
```

Difference between both condition is that with `if-let` you code will continue executing with next line of code after condition fails( if object is nil), but `guard-let` will stop execution and will throw return.

**Note: Default operator `??`**

You can also implement default "`operator: ??`" for assigning a default value like:

```
var str = obj.name ?? ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `if let`

```
if let name = obj.name as? String
{
   print(name)
}
else
{
   print("name is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what you're asking ... But from what I can tell you are looking for a way to handle the case where `obj.name` is nil.

You could write it like:

```
if obj.name == nil {
    // I am nil
} else {
    // I am not nil
}
```

or if you needed to capture the non-optional value how about:

```
if let name = obj.name {
    print(name) // I am not nil
} else {
    // I am nil
}
```

And im not sure why you would cast it to `Any` - generally if you can stick to concrete types you will save yourself a headache and pain down the road.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have your `Person` object:

```
class Person {
  var name: String?
}

let person = Person()
```

You can use `name` property in a few ways: using `if-let` or `?` operator.

```
// if-let construction
if let personName = person.name {
  print(personName.uppercased())
}

// `?` operator example
let uppercasedPersonName: String? = person.name?.uppercased()
```

For your case `if-let` is more likely to be what you want.